# Mocking companion object function in kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, powermock

I'm using PowerMock and Roboelectric and would like to mock a companion object function for a class. When I do this I get an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

What I have is basically this:

```
open class MockableClass private constructor(context: Context) {

    companion object {

        private val INSTANCE_LOCK = Any()
        private var sInstance: MockableClass? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context): MockableClass? {
            synchronized(INSTANCE_LOCK) {
                sInstance = (sInstance ?: MockableClass(context).let {
                    if (it.isValid) it
                    else null
                }
            }
            return sInstance
        }
    }

    init {
        // Do some initialization using context...
        // Set isValid to true/false depending on success
    }

    val isValid: Boolean
}
```

When I go to test this I will assume it will always work and would like to have getInstance just return a mocked version of the `MockableClass`.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
        constants = BuildConfig::class,
        sdk = intArrayOf(23))
@PowerMockIgnore("org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*")
@PrepareForTest(MockableClass::class)
class MyTest {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    @get:Rule
    val rule = PowerMockRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        context = RuntimeEnvironment.application as Context
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val instance = mock(MockableClass::class.java)
        mockStatic(MockableClass::class.java)
        `when`(MockableClass.getInstance(Matchers.isA(Context::class.java)))
                .thenReturn(instance)
        assertEquals(instance,
                MockableClass.getInstance(RuntimeEnvironment.application as Context))
    }
}
```

I've also tried mocking MockableClass.Companion::class.java with no luck.

Does anyone know what I need to do to be able to mock out this `getInstance` function?

Comment: I would remove Robolectric tag since it is question about Kotlin and reflection only.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't sure if the class loader had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I ended up doing...

Instead of mocking the static method I ended up using PowerMockito's `whenNew` function to return a mocked instance of `MockableClass`. The final code looks something like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
        constants = BuildConfig::class,
        sdk = intArrayOf(23))
@PowerMockIgnore("org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*")
@PrepareForTest(MockableClass::class)
class MyTest {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    @JvmField
    @Rule
    var rule = PowerMockRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        context = RuntimeEnvironment.application as Context
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val instance = mock(MockableClass::class.java)
        instance.isValid = true
        whenNew<MockableClass>("com.example.MockableClass")
                .withAnyArguments()
                .thenReturn(instance)
        assertEquals(instance, MockableClass.getInstance(context))
    }
}
```

Comment: Three days with this, and this totally helped. THANKS!